# What are the odds of never losing in a loaded coin game?

Tags: probability

Let's consider this simple dice game: A coin is faked so it has `p` chance to land on heads, and `1-p` chance to land on tails. Every round costs `$1`, and gives you `$2` if you win (for a total of `+$1`).

Assume you're starting with `$n`. What are your odds to "go infinite" - be able to play the game forever? This sounds like Markov Chains 101, it's just been ages since I read anything about Markov Chains.

**Also** - given any constant `m`, what are the odds of ever reaching `$m` in this game?

Comment: I can answer the second question: if $m < n$ then the probability is between $0$ and $1$, if $m \geq n$ then the probability is $1$.

Comment: @Yuval: The probability is most certainly not 1.  Imagine you start out with $1 and lose the first round...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $f(n)$ as the probability of playing forever when starting out with n coins. Also, assume that the probability p of winning a round is bigger than $\frac{1}{2}$ (otherwise, the probability of playing forever is 0). Then, we get the recurrence relation
$$
f(n) = p f(n + 1) + (1-p) f(n-1)
$$
with the boundary conditions $f(0) = 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = 1$.

The general solution of the recurrence relation is
$$
f(n) = a + b \left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^n
$$
and from the boundary conditions we get $a = -b = 1$. So, the probability to play infinitely is
$$
f(n) = 1 - \left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^n .
$$

The second question can be answered just as the first one, but with different boundary conditions: $f(0) = 0$ and $f(m) = 1$. This leads to the probability of reaching m as
$$
\frac{1 - \left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^n}{1 - \left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^m} .
$$

By the way, the keyword for this kind of problems is 'Random Walk'.